# The div container in HTML can be drag to resize width from left-to-right and right-to-left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Following from my Question, I have created a resize that can expand the width of a div. By pulling the right edge of the div to resize its width from left-to-right, on the other hand, do I have to resize the direction or how to resize from right-to-left?

[Example drag resizable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvfQc.png)

drag-resizable-container.component.html

```
<div id="resizer-container">
  <!-- [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height" [style.transform]="'translate3d(' + left + 'px,' + top + 'px,' + '0px)'" -->
  <div id="content-container" [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height" [style.transform]="getTranslate3D()">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div #graberWidth id="grabber-width" [ngStyle]="getGrabberDirection()" (pointerdown)="onMouseDown($event)" (pointerup)="onMouseUp($event)"></div>
</div>
```

drag-resizable-container.component.scss

```
div#resizer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //   div#content-container {
  //     flex-grow: 1;
  //   }

  div#grabber-width {
    width: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    // display: block;
    // right: 0px;
    cursor: col-resize;
  }
}
```

drag-resizable-container.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drag-resizable-container',
  templateUrl: './drag-resizable-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drag-resizable-container.component.scss'],
})
export class DragResizableContainerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() public width: number;
  @Input() public height: number;
  @Input() public resizeWidth = true;
  @Input() public resizeHeight = false;
  @Input() public left = 0;
  @Input() public top = 0;
  @Input() public expandDirection: 'LEFT' | 'RIGHT';
  @Input() public boxSpec = { left: 0, top: 0 }; // Where is consider movable area
  // @Input() public boxSpec: { left: number; top: number } = { left: 0, top: 0 }; // Where is consider movable area
  @Input() public willSetParent = false; // will dig the parent up to set the width and hegiht as well
  @Input() public willSetParentofParent = false; // will dig the parent up to set the width and hegiht as well
  public isResizing = false;

  private mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  private reqireInitWidht = false;
  private reqireInitHeight = false;

  constructor(
    // private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    if (!this.width) {
      this.width = 300;
      this.reqireInitWidht = true;
    }
    if (!this.height) {
      this.height = 300;
      this.reqireInitHeight = true;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.reqireInitWidht) {
        if (this.willSetParentofParent) {
          this.width = elem.parentElement.parentElement.clientWidth;
        }
        else {
          this.width = elem.parentElement.clientWidth;
        }
      }
      if (this.reqireInitHeight) {
        if (this.willSetParentofParent) {
          this.height = elem.parentElement.parentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        else {
          this.height = elem.parentElement.clientHeight;
        }
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  private updateWidthHeight(element: HTMLDivElement, width: number, height: number) {
    if (this.resizeWidth) {
      const widthPX = width.toString() + 'px';
      this.width = width;
      if (this.willSetParent) {
        element.parentElement.style.width = widthPX;
      }
      if (this.willSetParentofParent) {
        element.parentElement.parentElement.style.width = widthPX;
      }
    }
    if (this.resizeHeight) {
      const heightPX = height.toString() + 'px';
      this.height = height;
      if (this.willSetParent) {
        element.parentElement.style.height = heightPX;
      }
      if (this.willSetParentofParent) {
        element.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = heightPX;
      }
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.isResizing) {
      return;
    }
    const elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
    // console.log('ORIGINAL WIDTH OF CONTAINER', elem.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    // console.log('BOXSPEC', this.boxSpec);
    this.mouse = {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    };
    // TESTING: resize width from right to left
    const rootElementWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).width) - (parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize) * 4);
    // console.log('width size:', rootElementWidth);
    // console.log('x:', rootElementWidth - this.mouse.x);
    const [width, height] = [rootElementWidth - this.mouse.x - this.boxSpec.left, this.mouse.y - this.boxSpec.top];
    // console.log('UPDATED WIDTH OF DRAGABLE CONTAINER', width);
    this.updateWidthHeight(elem, width, height);
  }

  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent | Event) {
    this.isResizing = true;
  }

  onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent | Event) {
    this.isResizing = false;
  }

  getTranslate3D() {
    return 'translate3d(' + this.left + 'px,' + this.top + 'px,' + '0px)';
  }
  
  getGrabberDirection(){
    return this.expandDirection === 'LEFT' ? { right: '0px' } : { left: '0px' };
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can see what is currently not working for you?

Comment: @Phil I've revealed some code, check it out in the question topic

Comment: Whenever the user clicks on the 'grabber', you could set a state of `grabbed` to `true`, then whenever `grabbed` is `true` you could check the mouse event to see where the X axis of the mouse is relative to the screen, and according to that you can set the width of the div programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, resizing from right-to-left is only applied in a small cases, such as right navigation bar, etc.

So better not to serve option to resize from right-to-left.